# Can I get back my Boot Camp Windows partition?

Tags: macos, boot-camp

On my Mac, I had a Boot Camp partition that contained Windows 7. I recently got a new hard drive fitted, and have the one with the Boot Camp partition in an external USB enclosure.

Is it somehow possible to restore my old Boot Camp partition back to my new hard drive, or is it stuck in limbo for ever?

Answer (score 0):

Bit of an Mac OS X noob here, but would a linux 'live CD' or some kind of Partition Manager do this? Certainly within a DOS & Windows enviroment it's something i've done many times...

A disk level partition manager won't care about the type of filesystem on the hard drive, but i'd check with a Mac guru first :)

Comment: I think what you're suggesting could kinda work, but it sounds very scary! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using Boot Camp Assistant - it should be in the Utilities folder. It will allow you to erase the Windows partition and reclaim the space. See [Apple's FAQ](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4818#6).

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to reclaim the space, I want to somehow "move" that partition back onto the new hard disk..

Comment: According to the FAQ (look for that specific question) it's impossible to use Boot Camp with an external disk

Comment: That's what user41270 has already suggested, he/she wants to **move** the Boot Camp partition to the primary/internal disk.